# Periodic task is not working properly in django celery

Tags: python, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat, periodic-task

Hello friends I need your help in periodic tasks for django application. I am trying to do periodic task using celery but it is not properly working.   I have a simple task, in which there is only a print statement. Celery is working only for 1st time, and I also tried 'celery beat', but haven't got result

my "task.py" is

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from myapp.celery import app
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
from celery.registry import tasks

@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')), name="some_task")
def every_minute(a,b):
    print("This is running after one minute",a+b)
    return "task done"
tasks.register(every_minute)
```

and "view.py"

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from .tasks import *
from .models import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class CeleryTest(View):
    def get(self,request):
        send_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=200)
        task=every_minute.apply_async([5,6],etc=send_date)
        while not task.ready():
            print "calling............task is not ready"
        return HttpResponse("hi get ur task")
```

I just added this schedule in earlier celery setting."setting.py"

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {

     'every_minute': {
         'task': 'every_minute.add',
         'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
         'args': (5, 6),
     },
 }
```

Thank you friends for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use your Schedule like this....

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
      'every_minute': {
        'task': 'every_minute',
      },
}
```

and run this command for celery

```
python manage.py celeryd -BE -l info
```

now my periodic tasks running fine.